# How to buffer logstash logs to elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, amazon-ec2, logstash

I'm using ELK stack and wondered how to handle crises in my elastic search, what is the best practice to buffer logs coming from logstash to elastic search fails in case elastic search fails and logs keep coming.

Or in case you have a better solution to provide, in order to solve the problems with failing elastic search when we should keeping the logstash "live and on air"

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/having-buffer-points-your-elk-stack-important-pascal-lariv%C3%A9e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a Buffer (Redis, RabbitMQ ...) in front of your Logstash machine that will be the entry point for all log events that are shipped to your system. It will then buffer the data until the downstream components have enough resources to index.

Comment: Use redis as a buffer, shouldn't I use kafka or flume for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what your inputs actually are.  filebeat will stop sending data to logstash/elasticsearch if it is unable to connect.  Since it keeps track of where in the file it is, you get a distributed cache for free.  Note that you may have problems if the log file is rotated when the server is still down.

Comment: My input are logs entries coming from log4j socket to logstash

Comment: Then your choices are a broker (as Aboullaite mentioned), or you could have log4j write a file and then use filebeat to ship them over.  Personally, I use files whenever possible.

Comment: thanks for you input...i have approved the answer as it's also reasonable for me. i'll also consider using files to persist events

Comment: The joy of using files is that there are very few bugs or limitations in that part of the Elastic stack.  I've not found that to be true elsewhere.